# Getting 200 in response instead of 302

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to post multipart/form data using requests library according to website on submiting the form you are redirected to page where your data is created but when I am trying using requests library it gives 200 as response instead it should give 302 as response please could any one help me in this i dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Show us how do you make a call. Maybe you're getting 200 instead of 302 because your request automatically accepts and follows redirect?

Answer (score 4):

By default `requests` will follow "302" redirection responses. You can disable this as follows:

```py
r = requests.get('http://github.com/', allow_redirects=False)
```

See https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

Comment: Joe Halliwell i dont want to disable redirection i want it to happen but my problem is it is not happening after posting the form it stays that way with data filled and gives back 200 response